# CMIP6 data extraction for a cordinate with R

Tags: r

I'm doing a research about climate change and I want to extract the CMIP6 data for an especific cordinate in Santa watershed (Ancash, Peru) by using R.
I am getting de data from this website https://nex-gddp-cmip6.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/index.html#NEX-GDDP-CMIP6/
I would like to help me with a code for extracting the precipitation data.

Comment: These netCDF files are about 2.8 GB each (not suitable as example data), but these SO questions might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824192/extract-from-netcdf-files-using-x-y-coordinates, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280104/how-to-take-a-subset-from-a-netcdf-file-using-latitude-longitude-boundaries-in-r